# Почему здесь java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException?

Tags: java, junit, рефлексия, static

Может быть виной тому, что нижеприведённый код загружается именно во время JUnit теста? Эти параметры нужно во многих тестах, и я просто хотел считать эти параметры всего один раз.

```
class TestParams {
static final Properties PROPERTIES = getProperties();

static final int UNIT_ID = getUnitID();
static final SerialParameters SERIAL_PARAMETERS = getSerialParameters();

private static Properties getProperties() {
    Properties properties = new Properties();
    try (InputStream inputStream = TestParams.class.getClassLoader().getResourceAsStream("META-INF/ConnectionParams.properties")) {
        PROPERTIES.load(inputStream);
    } catch (IOException e) {
        fail();
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return properties;
}

private static SerialParameters getSerialParameters() {
    return new SerialParameters(
            PROPERTIES.getProperty("connection.port"),
            Integer.parseInt(PROPERTIES.getProperty("connection.baudRate")));
}

private static int getUnitID() {
    return Integer.parseInt(PROPERTIES.getProperty("vlf-60.id"), 16);
}
```

Но при обращении где-то в тестах в блоке @Before вот так:

```
params = TestParams.SERIAL_PARAMETERS;
```

на выходе получаю null. Ошибка java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException происходит на строке

```
Properties properties = new Properties();
```

Странно, что простое создание объекта через конструктор происходит через reflection. Только как этого избежать?

UPD: А вот так почему-то работает хорошо:

```
private static Properties getProperties() {
    Properties properties = null;
    try (InputStream inputStream = TestParams.class.getClassLoader().getResourceAsStream("META-INF/ConnectionParams.properties")) {
        properties = new Properties();
        properties.load(inputStream);
    } catch (IOException e) {
        fail();
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return properties;
}
```

Comment: напиши весь стектрейс

Comment: вы в методе `getProperties()` обращаетесь к полю `PROPERTIES`, которое должно быть инициализировано результатом работы метода.

Comment: @zRrr сделайте ответом.

Comment: Да, точно, типа цикла получается. "PROPERTIES.load(inputStream);" Это опечатка. C "properties.load(inputStream);" работает. Вот только непонятно, почему падает раньше, на строчке "Properties properties = new Properties();".

Comment: Как я могу сделать сообщение ответом? Нет такой кнопки